# set the filename after finish download in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I trying to develop Download manager app for iPhone. I am using this class for downloading operation:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

typealias CompleteHandlerBlock = () -> ()

class newDownloadObject: NSObject,NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    var session: NSURLSession!
    var handlerQueue: [String : CompleteHandlerBlock]!

    class var sharedInstance: newDownloadObject {
        struct Static {
            static var instance : newDownloadObject?
            static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = newDownloadObject()
            Static.instance!.handlerQueue = [String : CompleteHandlerBlock]()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }

    //MARK: session delegate
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: NSError?) {
        println("session error: \(error?.localizedDescription).")
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust))
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {        
        println("session \(session) has finished the download task \(downloadTask) of URL \(location).")
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        println("session \(session) download task \(downloadTask) wrote an additional \(bytesWritten) bytes (total \(totalBytesWritten) bytes) out of an expected \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) bytes.")

    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didResumeAtOffset fileOffset: Int64, expectedTotalBytes: Int64) {
        println("session \(session) download task \(downloadTask) resumed at offset \(fileOffset) bytes out of an expected \(expectedTotalBytes) bytes.")
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        if error == nil {
            println("session \(session) download completed")
        } else {
            println("session \(session) download failed with error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    func URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession(session: NSURLSession) {
        println("background session \(session) finished events.")  
        if !session.configuration.identifier.isEmpty {
            callCompletionHandlerForSession(session.configuration.identifier)
        }
    }

    //MARK: completion handler
    func addCompletionHandler(handler: CompleteHandlerBlock, identifier: String) {
        handlerQueue[identifier] = handler
    }

    func callCompletionHandlerForSession(identifier: String!) {
        if(identifier == nil){
            return
        }
        var handler : CompleteHandlerBlock = handlerQueue[identifier]!
        handlerQueue!.removeValueForKey(identifier)
        handler()
    }
}
```

this works great but i want to access downloaded file from itunes. therefor this file must be in Documents directory.

I try to move this file after finish download operation(`didFinishDownloadingToURL` method) to Document directory. However I get problem in here. The problem is the file name. It is like that 
"CFNetworkDownload_qsmwsB.tmp" and after downloading finished file it doesnt change to original name.( The file name must be "myBook.pdf" ) as a result I see ".tmp" file(s) in iTunes.

**How i can download a file directly to Documents directory or How i can change the filename after finish download?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thing what you where looking for is `downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.lastPathComponent` which gives you the original filename as provided in the URL.

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    println("session \(session) has finished the download task \(downloadTask) of URL \(location).")



    var error : NSError?
    var fileManager = NSFileManager()

    // this can be a class variable
    var docDirectoryURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/someDirectory/")

    // Get the original file name from the original request.
    var destinationFilename = downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.lastPathComponent
    // append that to your base directory
    var destinationURL =  docDirectoryURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(destinationFilename)

    /* check if the file exists, if so remove it. */
    if let path = destinationURL?.path {
        if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
            fileManager.removeItemAtURL(destinationURL!, error: nil);
        }
    }
    /*copy from the temp location to the final location*/
    var success = fileManager.copyItemAtURL(location, toURL: destinationURL!, error: &error)

    if (!success) {
        if let actualError = error {
            println("An Error Occurred: \(actualError)")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, I have similar this code. But The name of the file is not constant. How i can get file name from nsurlSession's methods.

Comment: I mean i send this class string array which contains Download Links. It creates thread for each of these links and start download. After finish downloding it gives CFNetworkDownload_randomSomething.tmp as name.